# How can I read Integer values from Excel using apache POI in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, excel

```
    import static org.testng.Assert.*;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    public class TestCalcAPI {
    CalcAPI clac = new CalcAPI();

    @DataProvider(name = " myData")
    public Integer[][] myData(){
        Integer[][] data = new Integer[][]{
            {4,2,2},
            {1,1,0},
            {-3,3,-6},
            {2,1,1} 
        };
        return data;
        }
    @DataProvider(name = "excelReading")
    public void myExcel() throws Exception 
    {
        File file = new File("DataInputForCalc.xls");

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        for (Row r : sheet)
        {
            int j = r.getLastCellNum();
            for (int i = 0; i<j;i++)
            {
                Integer res = (Integer)clac.addition(r.getCell(i+1).getNumericCellValue() , r.getCell(i+2).getNumericCellValue());
                assertEquals(res, r.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
            }

        }
    }


  @Test (dataProvider="myData")
  //public void testAdd(Integer exp,Integer a,Integer b)
  public void testAdd(Integer exp,Integer a,Integer b) {
      Integer res = clac.addition(a, b);
      assertEquals(res, exp);
  }
}
```

I have created CalcAPI class for add method and called an object of it clac.addition(a,b) for add method. I have used Integer values as an argument. In this TestNG class I have created annotation for DataProvider , one is hard coded data another is reading from Excel. And while reading from Excel I am not getting an option to read Integer values. So what should I use to read integer values from Excel

Comment: Check the cell type before reading the value from excel.

Comment: its general number type